# Splitting columns by values in a lookup table in R

Tags: r, merge, data.table, lookup

I have a table, one one line per hpo_term so a single patient can have many lines per ID.

```
ID hpo_term
123 kidney failure
123 hand tremor
123 kidney transplant
432 hypertension
432 exotropia
432 scissor gait
```

I have two other tables, one with kidney terms and other with non kidney terms, the kidney one looks like this:

```
kidney failure
kidney transplant
hypertension
```

The non kidney one looks like this:

```
hand tremor
exotropia
scissor gait
```

My desired outcome would be a table like this:

```
ID kidney_hpo_term                   non_kidney_hpo_term
123 kidney failure;kidney transplant hand tremor
432 hypertension                     exotropia;scissor gait
```

In reality there are hundreds of patients and hundreds of HPO terms.

I have access to base R; dplyr but I really don't know how one would approach this problem.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Edit:

The real table1 has many more extra columns that are not relevant and always the same per ID, I would want to import this across also. E.g.:

```
 ID hpo_term              year_of_birth  affected_relative   genome
    123 kidney failure    2000               Y                38
    123 hand tremor       2000               Y                38
    123 kidney transplant 2000               Y                38
    432 hypertension      1980               N                37
    432 exotropia         1980               N                37
    432 scissor gait      1980               N                37
```

Comment: Could you `dput(data)` to facilitate testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *different* approach using `tidyr::pivot_wider` using `values_fn` to summarise instead of doing it separately:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
pt.data %>% 
   mutate(kidney = hpo_term %in% kidney.hpo) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = kidney, values_from = hpo_term,
               values_fn = function(x)paste(x,collapse = ";"), values_fill = NA) %>%
   setNames(c("ID","Kidney","Non.kidney"))
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#     ID Kidney                           Non.kidney            
#  <int> <chr>                            <chr>                 
#1   123 kidney failure;kidney transplant hand tremor           
#2   432 hypertension                     exotropia;scissor gait
```

Data:

```
pt.data <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 432L, 432L, 432L), hpo_term = c("kidney failure", "hand tremor", "kidney transplant", "hypertension", "exotropia", "scissor gait")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
kidney.hpo <- c("kidney failure", "kidney transplant", "hypertension")
```

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to respond. This works well, I have accepted it as it reduces the need for the second table, which is an approach I didn't think about and saves me time!

Comment: Dear @Ian I have edited the question as the full table is quite a lot longer, does this alter the solution at all? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)

table1 = data.frame(ID = c(123,123,123,432,432,432),
                    hpo_term = c("kidney failure","hand tremor","kidney transplant","hypertension","exotropia","scissor gait"))

kid_terms = c("kidney failure","kidney transplant","hypertension")
nonkid_terms = c("hand tremor","exotropia","scissor gait")

table1$term_type = NA
table1$term_type[table1$hpo_term %in% kid_terms] = "kidney_hpo_term"
table1$term_type[table1$hpo_term %in% nonkid_terms] = "non_kidney_hpo_term"

table2 = table1 %>% group_by(ID,term_type) %>%
  summarize(term_list=paste(hpo_term,collapse=";")) %>%
  spread(term_type,term_list)

> table2
    ID kidney_hpo_term                  non_kidney_hpo_term   
1   123 kidney failure;kidney transplant hand tremor           
2   432 hypertension                     exotropia;scissor gait
```

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

table1 = data.table(ID = c(123,123,123,432,432,432),
                    hpo_term = c("kidney failure","hand tremor","kidney transplant","hypertension","exotropia","scissor gait"))

kid_terms = c("kidney failure","kidney transplant","hypertension")
nonkid_terms = c("hand tremor","exotropia","scissor gait")

table1$term_type = NA
table1$term_type[table1$hpo_term %in% kid_terms] = "kidney_hpo_term"
table1$term_type[table1$hpo_term %in% nonkid_terms] = "non_kidney_hpo_term"

table2 = table1[,.(term_list=paste(hpo_term,collapse=";")),by=.(ID,term_type)]

table3 = dcast(table2, ID~term_type, value.var = "term_list")

> table3
    ID                  kidney_hpo_term    non_kidney_hpo_term
1: 123 kidney failure;kidney transplant            hand tremor
2: 432                     hypertension exotropia;scissor gait
```

Comment: works well, thanks for taking the time to respond. I've accepted another answer as I hadn't thought of summarising rather than having two hpo lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
patients %>%
  left_join(terms) %>%
  group_by(ID, type) %>%
  summarize(ID.hpo_term = paste(ID.hpo_term, collapse = ", "), .groups = "drop") %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = ID.hpo_term)
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "ID.hpo_term"
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     ID kidney_hpo_term                   non_kidney_hpo_term    
  <dbl> <chr>                             <chr>                  
1   123 kidney failure, kidney transplant hand tremor            
2   432 hypertension                      exotropia, scissor gait
```

Input data

```
patients <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ID = c(123, 123, 123, 432, 432, 432),
       ID.hpo_term = c("kidney failure",
                       "hand tremor","kidney transplant","hypertension",
                       "exotropia","scissor gait")
)


terms <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  type = rep(c("kidney_hpo_term", "non_kidney_hpo_term"), each = 3),
  ID.hpo_term = c("kidney failure", "kidney transplant",
                       "hypertension",
                       "hand tremor","exotropia","scissor gait")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!